# Reading multiple files and extracting 1st column using scala

Tags: scala

I am starting to learn Scala and got into this simple problem. I am used to doing this using Unix command line with Bash and Awk but I decided to use Scala for learning.

I want to parse multiple text file which are tab separated and want to extract 1 or any arbitrary column.

I also want to remove lines that start with "#" which I was able to do.

The code below will print first row from a specific column from each file.
**How do I get it to print all the rows?**

```
import scala.io.Source

if (args.length > 0){

    for (arg<-args){
        val file= Source.fromFile(arg).getLines.filter(s => !(s contains "#")).mkString("\n").split("\t")
        println(file(2))    
    }
}

else
Console.err.println("Please enter filename")
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling mkString("\n") on getLines will result in a single string of the entire file and that is the reason you are seeing output for first row alone.

The following code snippet should be working:

```
  if (args.length > 0) {
    for (arg <- args) {
      println(Source.fromFile(arg).getLines().filterNot(_.trim.startsWith("#")).map(_.split("\t")(2)).mkString("\n"))
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using for comprehensions. The below code will return the second column. Just change the hardcoded value 1 to whichever column you want.

```
 {for {
      line <- Source.fromFile("test.txt").getLines
      if(!(line contains "#"))
     } 
     yield line.split("\t")(1)
}.toList
```